# useEffect executes with stale information

Tags: react-hooks

If I have a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
 const [text, setText] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    async function run() {
      // fetch new text when some prop changes
      const newText = await fetchText();

      // to exaggerate the effect of waiting,
      // let's sleep for two seconds
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
      setText(newText);
    }
    run();
  }, [some_prop]);
```

Every time `some_prop` changes, I fetch new text from an endpoint. Suppose `run` takes 3 seconds to finish. If the value of `some_prop` changes more often that, `useEffect` will still resolve all the async calls to `run`. Suppose `some_prop` changes from `a -> b -> c -> d -> e` in one second. I would like to see the value of `text` go smoothly from `a` to `e`, but it will flash through all the intermediate values (`b -> c -> d`) as the calls to `run` finish. How can I throw away those intermediate calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `let` variable (`cancel`) to the `useEffect` block, and if the `useEffect` is called, set `cancel` to `true`. If `cancel` is called, avoid setting the state.

Note: The obvious solution in the example is to cancel the `timeout`, but the `timeout` simulates an api call.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState, useEffect } = React;

  const Demo = () => {
    const [num, setN] = useState(0);
    const [text, setText] = useState('Text: ');

    useEffect(() => {
      let cancel = false;
      
      async function run() {
        // simulate api call
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
        
        if(cancel) return;
        
        setText(`Text: ${num * 10}`);
      }
      run();
      
      return () => {
        cancel = true;
      };
    }, [num]);

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setN(n => n + 1)}>{num}</button>

        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM
    .createRoot(root)
    .render(<Demo />);
</script>
```

One caveat is that the `api` is getting called needlessly, and we don't cancel the requests. We can cancel the actual request, by using `fetch` or any a library that supports cancelling (axios for example).

If you're using `fetch`, you just need to pass the `signel` from an abort controller.

```
fetch(url, { signal })
```

Read the docs of other libraries to see how they can be cancelled.

This example uses an abort controller to cancel the timeout.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState, useEffect } = React;

  const Demo = () => {
    const [num, setN] = useState(0);
    const [text, setText] = useState('Text: ');

    useEffect(() => {
      const controller = new AbortController();
      const signal = controller.signal;
      
      async function run() {
        // simulate api call
        await new Promise(r => {
          const timeout = setTimeout(r, 2000);
          
          signal.addEventListener('abort', () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
          });
        });
        
        setText(`Text: ${num * 10}`);
      }
      run();
      
      return () => {
        controller.abort();
      };
    }, [num]);

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setN(n => n + 1)}>{num}</button>

        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM
    .createRoot(root)
    .render(<Demo />);
</script>
```

Comment: @choc0chips - see the 2nd solution as well.